# Is it proper to ask about cpu specs?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

I want to post a question about if a laptop I have my eyes on is powerful enough for hardcore gaming. Basically, is it ok to ask questions about software in collaboration with games on the website?

Comment: Define "hardcore gaming." You can find an existing community that does this at http://reddit.com/r/buildapc (or, more poignantly, http://www.reddit.com/r/suggestalaptop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't allow questions that want to know whether a specific computer can, or can't, run a specific game.  It's too narrow to be applicable to the general population of the internet.  That's exactly what system requirements are for.  To expand it to, "Can this laptop handle hardcore gaming?" doesn't expand the question sufficiently to be all that useful.

As for hardcore gaming, what defines that?  Which games you can play?  How well you can play your games?  How much heat you generate while gaming?  There's nothing there for us to use to be able to answer, as it's not a definition that's objective in any sense.

So, no, a question asking that would not be acceptable here, as not only would it be too narrow to help others, but it wouldn't be defined enough to even answer, even if we did allow it here.

Answer (score -1):

In general "Will Game X run on my machine?" questions are not really welcome here and this is basically the same, it's just asking for multiple games.

While we do allow certain hardware/software specific questions in relation to gaming, some members in our community (me included) are hovering over the downvote button if they see [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) or a system specification in the question itself. You need to be really specific and the question should be a more general one. Most of the time you see hardware details, there's a good chance that this question is simply really too localized.

If we allowed these questions, the main problem would be that there were a lot of "Can I run game X with my system" questions. We wouldn't be able to close them as a duplicate, but they are still basically the same.

Questions that would be allowed are things like [How to buy a Card](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2908/how-do-i-buy-a-graphics-card). These are perfectly on-topic here and they can also be helpful in a "Can I run X" question. But before you ask another of these: take a look if there isn't already a thread about it somewhere.